# White Screen Issue while navigating in Xamarin forms Prism MasterDetails Page

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, navigation, prism, master-detail

I have implemented MasterDetail Page using xamarin forms prism and I have following Pages in my app.
1) Master 
2) Home 
3) Employee 
4) Profile

-- Initially App is set to Master - Home (Detail Page) page after login. From Home page i navigate to Employee (Detail Page) using code as follows :

```
  await _navigationService.NavigateAsync("NavigationPage/Employee");
```

-- From Employee Page I navigate to Profile (Content Page - Non Detail page) by clicking on one of the employees using code:

```
 await _navigationService.NavigateAsync("Profile", lstparam, null, false);
```

-- Once home button is clicked in profile page, i want to navigate to Master - Home (Detail Page) . However it navigates to Employee (Detail Page) .

```
await _navigationService.GoBackToRootAsync();
```

Checked navigation stack by debugging , It was only showing Employee (Detail Page) Page in it. Also tried navigation to home page by using following code :

```
await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("/Master/NavigationPage/Home");
```

The above code is working and i can navigate to Home (Detail Page) , but I am getting White Screen while navigating to Profile to Home Page .

Attached Screenshots . Please Help .Thanks in Advance.

[MasterPage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddKGu.png)

[Details_Home](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLjES.png)

[Details_Employee](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXeb9.png)

[Profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kX3Hm.png)

[Whitescreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpSfl.png)

Comment: What's the result from the navigation? Exception?

Comment: No . I dont get any exception . The code await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("/Master/NavigationPage/Home"); actually works. But it displays white screen for a moment during transition from profile to home page and then navigates to home page. I think its because of pushing multiple pages i.e. "/Master/NavigationPage/Home" at a time in navigation stack . Pushing employee and profile pages works fine for me without any white screen issue.

Comment: What is the result of `await NavigateAsync(...)`?

Comment: I have a similar issue, with NavigationPage (PushAsync), it seems during a transiation the target page is loaded also async and as long it is not loaded yet you see a blank page. There seems to be no solution at the moment. I could only figure out to set the background color of the blank page. On faster devices i do not recognize this transiation.

Comment: @Haukinger Did you mean to ask which page it navigates to ?

Comment: @TanmayKanekar I mean "what is `INavigationResult.Success` and what is `INavigationResult.Exception`?" on the navigation result returned by `NavigateAsync`

Comment: @Haukinger I tried debugging Prism.Navigation.INavigationService _navigationService object in _navigationService.NavigateAsync("/...") but could not find INavigationResult.Success 
and INavigationResult.Exception and also tried to check navigation result returned by NavigateAsync as you suggested but found that _navigationService.NavigateAsync("/...") is a void method which does not return Error and success in navigation .  
Is there any workaround for navigating to Home (Detail Page) from Profile (Content page) without encountering white screen issue.

Comment: How exactly are you `await`ing a `void` method?

Comment: Are you using `Shell`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/flyout ?

Answer (score 3):

I recently had a very similar problem but it did not depend on prism.
I wanted to create an autologin features by bypassing the login (ContentPage) and calling the homepage (Master And Detail Page).
To do this I had to call the async login service method in my application class.
in order:

1. Call async service
2. Call NavigationService.NavigateAsync

In this case appears a blank page

To Solve:

1. Call NavigationService.NavigateAsync
2. Call async service

Comment: what are you referring to with ASYNC SERVICE?

Comment: An asynchronous service could be a component that returns the result of a rest call or an internal call to the database

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it happened to me for being using the wrong NavigationService.
I had a **static** `Navigator` class that I've been using it for managing and Logging navigations in the App (a simple wrapper), which has a property called `Instance`, of type `NavigationService` that I was setting it to the NavigationService of the App.xaml.cs

Reassigning it on each ViewModel (in the ViewModelBase's constructor) fixed the white page bug for me.
Hope it helps someone!